# Ruby include check and iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, loops

I have an array:

```
art_groups_arr = []
```

I'm getting it from:

```
art_groups_arr << a.art_name (in loop)
```

When I try to check for inclusion, I get `can't convert Array into String`

I tried:

```
n2.art_group.include?(art_groups_arr.map { |e| e})
```

In my view my array looks like:

```
["Амортизатор", "Защитный колпак / пыльник, амортизатор"]
```

How can I correctly loop and check `include?`?

Comment: You're passing the entire array to include? when you should just be passing a single element. And what the heck is that pointless map doing there?

Comment: so how to check include on each element of array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check every element of one array to see if it's in another array:

```
art_groups_arr.each do |group|
  n2.art_group.include? group
end
```

If you want to see if the arrays contain the exact same elements you can do this:

```
art_groups_arr.sort == n2.art_group.sort
```

Comment: thank's... done 5 minute ago by myself.... 2 night without sleep) i'm like a zombie, didn't think so good...